# supervisord http://localhost:9001 refused connection

Tags: supervisord

Despite much effort trying all solutions posted on stackoverflow, I still cannot manage solving this.

The problem (Case 1):

```
$ sudo supervisorctl -c /app/vpn_bot/supervisord.conf
http://localhost:9001 refused connection
```

Case 2:

```
$ sudo supervisorctl -c /app/vpn_bot/supervisord.conf
unix:///tmp/supervisorctl.sock refused connection
```

Here is the relevant `supervisord.conf` file:

```
[supervisord]
# nodaemon=true
[supervisorctl]
# case 1: serverurl=http://127.0.0.1:9001
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisorctl.sock # case 2

[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisorctl.sock

[inet_http_server]
port=127.0.0.1:9001

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface
```

I have made sure `sudo supervisord -c /app/vpn_bot/supervisord.conf` is running, and port `9001` is not used by any other process.

Any one can offer some help here?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04, in case that is useful

Comment: Problem solved itself after I logged in the next day, still not sure what could have caused this

Comment: Just check if you are running **supervisord** daemon?